# Radio button onclick - change span content

Tags: jquery, ajax, radio-button

Is it possible to do this with jQuery AJAX?

I'd like to change the content of a `<span>` when a radio button is selected.

```
<input class="unitSelectInches" type="radio" name="units" value="inches" />Inches
<input class="unitSelectCenti" type="radio" name="units" value="centi" />Centimetres
```

Selecting inches will change this span to say "inches" and centimetres too...

```
<span class="unitLabel">inches</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're confused, jQuery and Ajax are 2 different things. You just need jQuery for your requirement, ajax is not related at all.

Please try this

```
$('input[name="units"]').change(function() {
    $('.unitLabel').text(this.value);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/37Dh9/)

Answer (score 1):

did not you want it?

```
$("input[name=units]").on("change", function () {
   var selected = $("input[name=units]:checked");
   $(".unitLabel").text( selected.val());
 });
```

Comment: Actually you want the `:checked` selector... `:selected` is for `option` elements of a `select` element. http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/